# TCP Losing connection

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I have created a client and server and I'm able to successfully send a file from my client and receive it on the server. A problem occurs though when I send a file successfully then if I try to send another file my connection fails. I don't understand why this is occurring. Any insight would be great, I don't have much experience with socket programming.

client.cpp

```
int sock, n;
unsigned int length;
struct sockaddr_in server, from;
struct hostent *hp;
string send_file;
cout << "Enter filename: ";
cin >> send_file;

FILE *file_read;
unsigned long fsize;

// get file size
file_read = fopen(send_file.c_str(), "rb");
if (file_read == NULL){
    cout << "file doesn't exist."<< endl;
    break;
 }
 else{
     fseek(file_read, 0, SEEK_END);
     fsize = ftell(file_read);
     rewind(file_read);
     cmd_msg.size= fsize;

 }

// receive first UDP message
n = recvfrom(sock,&cmd_rec,sizeof(cmd_rec),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server, &length); //1B
if (n < 0){
    exit(1);
 }

int tcp_port=cmd_rec.port;


int sk;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *serverTCP;

//create TCP socket
sk = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sock < 0){
    exit(1);
 }

serverTCP = gethostbyname(server_host);
if (serverTCP==0){
    exit(1);
 }

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)serverTCP->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,serverTCP->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = tcp_port;
if (connect(sk,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
    cout << "failed to create connection. "<<endl; // this is the error received when trying to send second file
    exit(1);
 }

while (true){
    //buffer size of 1448
    unsigned char buff[1448]={0};
    int bytes_read = fread(buff,1,1448,file_read);

    // send data with successful read
    if(bytes_read > 0){
        write(sk, buff, bytes_read);
    }

    //exit when end of file is reached
    if (bytes_read < 1448){
        if (feof(file_read)){
        }
        break;
    }
 }
fclose(file_read);
```

server.cpp

```
int sk, sk2;
socklen_t clilen;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
int n;

// create TCP socket
sk = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sk < 0){
    exit(1);
 }

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = 0;                    // let system choose port
if (bind(sk, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
    exit(1);
 }

socklen_t len = sizeof(serv_addr);
if (getsockname(sk, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, &len) == -1){
    exit(1);
 }

int listening = serv_addr.sin_port ;
cmd_rec.port=listening;

//send UDP message
n = sendto(sock,&cmd_rec,sizeof(cmd_rec),0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,fromlen); //1B
if (n < 0){
    exit(1);
 }

cout << "- listen @: " << listening << endl;
listen(sk,5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
sk2 = accept(sk, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
if (sk2 < 0){
    cout << "- failed to accept connection. " << endl;
 }
 else{
     cout << "- connected with client" << endl;
 }

FILE *file_write;
string backup= "backup/";
string location= backup+cmd_msg.filename;

file_write = fopen(location.c_str(), "w");
int bytes_rec=0;
int bytes_sum=0;
char rec_buffer[1448];
//loop to write data chunks to server
while((bytes_rec = read(sk2, rec_buffer, 1448)) > 0){
    bytes_sum=bytes_rec+bytes_sum;
    cout << "- total bytes received: " << bytes_sum <<endl;
    fwrite(rec_buffer, 1,bytes_rec,file_write);

    //once end of file is reached break the loop
    if(bytes_sum ==cmd_msg.size){
        break;
    }
 }

fclose(file_write);
```

Comment: Where are you setting up the UDP socket?

Comment: Which call is getting the error? What error is it getting? Call `perror()` before exiting when you get an error, so you can see the reason.

Comment: I'm receiving the error after the connect function call in the client

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but in `client.cpp` I noticed this incompleteness: `if (bytes_read < 1448){ if (feof(file_read)){} break; }` and in any case use of `feof()` is suspicious.

Comment: @Anthony And what error code are you receiving?

Comment: @Barmer the error is connection refused

Comment: It looks like your server program only calls accept() once, and then exits after the socket session is complete.  If that's the case, that would explain why you get "connection refused" for the second connection attempt -- the server isn't running anymore.

Comment: When I send the second file the server file is ran from the top again though so it should be able to accept the second connection.

Comment: It might help to watch the connection using `tcpdump` or possibly `wireshark`.

Comment: Anthony, it may or may not be the case that the server got restarted but it is indisputable that when the client tried the second connection there was was nothing listening at the port. @JeremyFreisner is correct.

Comment: @EJP I'm sorry but I don't understand. My thought process is that I have a "connect" call in my client and an "accept" call in the server. These match up and would create my connection to send my file.